# Buffer with bufferedreader.readLine () returns null unexpectedly

Tags: java, android

I have problems using BufferedReader when I use `readLine ()` it returns null value. This is my code:

How can I discover the source of the problem?

BackgroundTask_GET.java

```
public class BackgroundTask_GET extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
String duongdan = MainActivity.SERVER_NAME;
TextView tvResult;
String strName, strScore;
String str;
ProgressDialog pDialog;
Context context;

public String TAG = "GG";

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    pDialog.setMessage("Sending...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
}

public BackgroundTask_GET(Context context, TextView tvResult, String 
strName, String strScore) {
    this.tvResult = tvResult;
    this.strName = strName;
    this.strScore = strScore;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    duongdan += "?name=" + this.strName + "&score=" + this.strScore;
    try {
        URL url = new URL(duongdan);
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) 
url.openConnection();
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
        String line = "";
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        Log.d(TAG, "bfr:" + urlConnection);
        while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
            Log.d(TAG, "append"+sb.append(line));
        }
        str = sb.toString();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: " + str);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "exception " + e);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "exception " + e);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    if (pDialog.isShowing()) {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    tvResult.setText(str);
    Log.d("RESULT", "khanh" + str);
}
```

}

`` `MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener {
public static final String SERVER_NAME = 
"http://192.168.1.2/AndroidNetworking_server/student_GET.php";

private EditText edtName, edtScore;
private Button btnSend;
private TextView tvResult;

String strName, strScore;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    edtName = findViewById(R.id.edtName);
    edtScore = findViewById(R.id.edtScore);
    btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
    tvResult = findViewById(R.id.tvResult);
    btnSend.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSend:
            strName = edtName.getText().toString();
            strScore = edtScore.getText().toString();
            BackgroundTask_GET backgroundTask = new 
BackgroundTask_GET(this, tvResult, strName, strScore);
            backgroundTask.execute();
            break;
     }
   }
}
```

Error: 
~

`` ` 1 ` ``
    2019-07-15 14:07:58.065 24764- 28936/com.example.lab2_khanhpd02377_androidnetworkingD/GG:bfr:com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl:http://192.168.1.2/AndroidNetworking_server/student_GET.php?name=4&score=5
~

`` ` 2 ` ``
    2019-07-15 14:07:58.066 24764- 28936/com.example.lab2_khanhpd02377_androidnetworking D/GG: doInBackground:

Comment: It returns null at end of stream, which is why you use it as the loop termination condition. If the *first* `readLine()` returns `null`, the stream was empty. NB Don't use `HttpConnection.disconnect()` unless you know why you are doing so. You need to close the input stream.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not good at showing.
And this is the second time I asked this question, maybe I'll have to say more about the problem I have. Anyway, thanks for your comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see a couple of problems with your code:

1. The `readLine()` method returns the line with the line separator *removed*.  So

   ```
   while ((line = bfr.readLine()) != null) {
       sb.append(line);
   }
   ```

   will strip line separators while reading.
2. You are not checking the HTTP response code.  If the response code is not a 2xx code, then `getInputStream()` will throw an exception.

   The response code can be found using `getResponseCode()`. The error response body can be read using `getErrorStream()`.
3. As @user207421 says, you shouldn't call `urlConnection.disconnect()` unless you really need to disconnect.  If you don't need to, it is better to let the HTTP client library deal with disconnection.  (It may be able to keep the connection open, and use it for later requests to the same server.)
4. You *should*<sup>1</sup> close the `BufferedReader`, and ideally you should do it using *try-with-resources*.

---

<sup>1 - I won't say *must* because there are scenarios where it won't matter.  However, if you don't close the stream, one way or another, you will leak file descriptors which could lead to errors later on.   And, it is certainly good practice to close streams ... because you never *really* know if your code might be used / reused in the future in some context where the resource leak does matter.</sup>

---

**UPDATE** - I think you are saying that the real real cause for the `null` / empty stream was on the PHP side.  Notwithstanding that, you probably ought to address the four issues that I mentioned: line separators, response code, disconnect and using try-with-resource.

Comment: I use "urlConnection.disconnect()" because i have use "ProgressDialog". I want it to pay me the results and the end. Sorry for not sharing more than my code.
You can see link php above above the log section .I want to read it and the result is a null value

Comment: Sorry, no.  Surely you have a lecturer or a teacher who you can ask.  Or a friend.

Comment: You're right.
Perhaps finding a problem by asking someone can help me understand the problem thank you

Comment: Many thanks i for fixing the problem. That is due to the php file. Sorry for not reading your answer carefully. By the way, I'm not good at English and I use google translation

Comment: If it's not 2xx he will get an *exception*, and he *must* close the `BufferedReader`. 'Should' is not sufficient.

Comment: It is not up to you or me to tell him what he "must" do.  Besides, 1) If he is only doing this download once (or a small number of times) then the resource leak is moot,  and 2) this is a student project, so no kittens will die if he gets it wrong.